# Angular 4: Infinite scroll not working

Tags: angular, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

I have tried using ngx-infinite-scroll (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-infinite-scroll) and also some other directives but none seem to work.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.0.2",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.2",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.2",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"absurd": "^0.3.8",
"angular2-masonry": "^0.4.0",
"animate.css": "^3.5.2",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
"metismenu": "^2.7.0",
"ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
"ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.5.1",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0"
}
```

**user.component.html**

```
<div class="row" infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="0" 
  [infiniteScrollThrottle]="300" (scrolled)="loadMore()">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4" *ngFor="let user of userList">
     <span>{{user.name}} ({{user.email}})</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**user.module.ts**

The import is done

```
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    InfiniteScrollModule
  ],
  declarations: [UserComponent],
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
})
export class UserModule { }
```

**user.component.ts**

```
export class UserComponent {

  constructor() {}

  loadMore() {
    console.log('method begins');
  }
}
```

Tried using host listener as well but the scroll event just doesn't seem to occur.
Has it got anything to do with the class i'm using on which the infinite scroll is applied?

Comment: Check Angular 7 material infinite virtual scroll example here https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-implement-infinite-virtual-scroll-in-few-easy-steps-in-latest-angular-7-x/

Answer (score 30):

Inside the [document](https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll) has mentioned about.

> By default, the directive listens to the window scroll event and
>   invoked the callback. To trigger the callback when the actual element
>   is scrolled, these settings should be configured:
>
> 1. [scrollWindow]="false"
> 2. set an explict css "height" value to the element

Therefore, just put the height: 100% on your container and you will see the scrolled fired.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    styles: [
        `.search-results {
            height: 20rem;
            overflow: scroll;
        }`
    ],
    template: `
        <div class="search-results"
            infiniteScroll
            [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
            [infiniteScrollThrottle]="500"
            (scrolled)="onScroll()"
            [scrollWindow]="false">
        </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    onScroll () {
        console.log('scrolled!!')
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the scrollWindow hint! That took me hours! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
       <div
         [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
         [infiniteScrollUpDistance]="1.5"
         [infiniteScrollThrottle]="100"
         (scrolled)="onScrollDown()"
         [scrollWindow]="false"class="search-results">
       <div  *ngFor="let user of userList">
        <span>{{user.name}} ({{user.email}})</span>
       </div>
       </div>
```

.search-results{
  height : 100%
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

use above HTML code it works fine  --[ngx-infinite-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

all i did was
changing ngx-infinite-scroll version to be compatiable with my angular version
i use angular 12

**in package.json**

```
ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1"
```

remove node_modules and package-lock.json
then run :

```
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set height of your container div

```
<div class="row" style="height: 90%"
  infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="0" 
  [infiniteScrollThrottle]="300" (scrolled)="loadMore()">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4" *ngFor="let user of userList">
     <span>{{user.name}} ({{user.email}})</span>
   </div>
</div>
```