# Angular 4: Lazy Loading plugin to fetch next set of records on demand

Tags: angular, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

I've tabular data which would cross thousands of records, Initially only 1000 records would be populated in the grid. upon scroll, the next 1000 records would be appended on each scroll till all the records are populated.

Furthermore I shouldn't have page level scroll i.e., overflow: none for the body and the content level scroll on the div would be present.

I've tried [infinite Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43914699/angular-4-infinite-scroll-not-working) link but it doesn't satisfy my requirement, the scroll event gets triggered only where page level scroll is available but not when we apply infinite scroll on the content level.

Can you let me know if any alternative plugins available to fetch next set of records on demand scroll or any suggestion on how to apply infinite scroll on content level is also appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting property as scrollWindow false made the content level scroll infinitely..