# NGX infinite scroll won't work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, infinite-scroll

I want to implement infinite scroll and I am using ngx-infinite-scroll, but the onScroll() function is not triggered. I have tried everything I've seen on other questions but with no success.
I want to use ngx-infinite-scroll with angular material table.

```
 <div
  infiniteScroll 
  [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" 
  [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50" 
  (scrolled)="onScroll()">
</div>


onScroll() {
   console.log("Scroll...");
}
```

Comment: Syntactically I don't see any problem, we'll need to see more of your code -- where you declare onScroll(), imported module etc

Comment: @JoshuaChan on my component, where the template is

Comment: I suggest setting up a stackblitz that reproduces the problem.

Comment: now I see, I have a scroll bar from overflow: scroll, but it is disabled

Comment: but I want to use my window scroll bar

Comment: The library defaults to listening window scroll instead of the actual element scroll anyway, however it might follow the actual element's offsetHeight for triggering (scrolled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE
This is answering the question without using ngx-infinite-scroll
Use

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
scrolled() {
}
```

Or window:scroll

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
scrolled() {
```

Comment: I am going to delete my answer I failed to see that you are already using an existing directive. Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/44899396/2103767

Comment: Also try what I gave in your component for debugging. I will be deleting my answer after you try.

Comment: Just making sure that you seeing the browsers scroll bar?

Comment: I am seeing the scroll bar, I have some text loaded so I can scroll

Comment: You may want to add stackblitz plnkr.

Comment: I found the problem, it was an position: absolute; .Yeah nice. Thanks for help.